# Book dealing with PDEs of the form $u_t=\Delta u+f(t,u)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, reference-request, parabolic-pde

Hi I have background on ordinary differential equations of the form $$u'=f(t,u).$$

I am interested in using what I know about ODE to learn aspect of partial differential equations of the form

$$u_t=\Delta u+f(t,u)$$
with Dirichlet/Neuman boundary conditions.

I am used to ODE, so when I see a problem of the form $u_t=\Delta u+f(t,u)$, I see an additional challenge which is the space variable $x$ and the Laplacian. The way I usually see people deal with this challenge is to multiply the PDE by $u$ then integrating over the domain $\Omega$ so they obtain a differential inequality with only a time variable.

I am looking for a book that deals with equations of the form $u_t=\Delta u+f(t,u)$, specially:

- existence of solution on $[0,\infty )$ (global existence)
- positive solutions ($u_0>0$ implies $u(t,x)>0$ for all $t,x$)
- asymptotic behaviour

Comment: I think the problem can be boiled down to finding the Greens function for the Heat eqn and that gives you an integral representation of your solution for any f, from which you can check existence or asymptotic behavior.

Comment: @Dk65 I don't think a Green's function for the heat equation is strictly enough because of the dependence on $u$ in $f$.

Comment: Take a look at Henry's book: https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9783540105572

Comment: A great book (but a difficult one) is *Second Order Parabolic Differential Equations* by G. M. Lieberman. This goes the existence, uniqueness and regularity theory of such equations. He also addresses semilinear equations (such as yours) and even fully nonlinear equations.